# How to set environments for release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image: Environmetn set up]

Hi, I saw several images of feature which allows to gruup variables for different environments for same release pipeline. Here is another  [exampe](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/managing-configuration-app-settings-for-multiple-environments-in-your-cd-pipeline/)

But I am not able to see this in my dev ops portal. How can I activate this option ?

Below is my 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am not able to see this in my dev ops portal. How can I activate this option ?

I agree with klabranche. As we know, MS is working hard to provide better Azure Devops, so Azure Devops has very fast iterative updates and lots of specific optimizations at different stages.

That document is more than two years old (April 5th, 2017), and the `Environments` is an old concept. In my experience, MS updated the new icons and names for Azure DevOps all up and each of  services within Azure DevOps([Introducing Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch)) (September 10, 2018), change the name **Environments** to **Stages**.

This is the reason why you not able to see this in your dev ops portal. Now, we could defined the variables in the Variables directly, then select the scope for each variable. We do not need to open another window to define variables for each Stage:

[image]

I hope this answer can help you get out of the puzzle.

Comment: Stages are not sutable, because I need same steps but with different variables. New stage cannot use steps from another. I know there is a Task Group concept wich allow to use same steps, but it is not so conveniant also, it will requure map Stage variables to Group variables.

Comment: @SergSh - You just recreate the step in the stage you need it in and use the variable you created mapped to the stage?  IE - If you have ConnectionStringX and three stages Dev, QA, Prod then you have ConnectionStringX three times in your variable list with each mapped to each stage.  Even if your Dev & QA variable value are the same, you repeat it.

Comment: @SergSh, Obviously this is another question, different from your previous (I am not able to see this in my dev ops portal. How can I activate this option ?). And we can't go back to the previous version. You should post your question based on Azure Devops current version and find the solution instead of use the old version.

Comment: @SergSh, I could understand you said "same steps but with different variables,  New stage cannot use steps from another", how can environment do it? Please try update your question with some details info or a sample for your new request.

Comment: I see from image, I have posted that same stage and steps is linked to different environments which have different variables values. Not obvious but I assume they have same variable set but with dufferent values. My question wehere is this f**g feature? Is it real or or not? Enfironments is not old concept BTW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops

Comment: The images you have are from an older version.  Environment was renamed to stages.  The variables in each Environment that you saw is now in one tab called Variables and you set your variables in each stage.

Comment: The docs you just linked to is for the latest version of DevOps Server.  What version of DevOps are you on / using?  Names/tabs, etc... have changed between versions....  In the docs you just attached to you can create an "environment of sources to target (servers)."  The environment can then be used in the Release Pipeline.  It's a way of reusing the same servers in multiple Release Pipelines without having to redefine them in each pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Edit your release pipeline and select the variables tab.  Next to each variable is a scope setting.  Select the scope you want for each variable (QA,Staging,Prod).

This means that if you have a variable that is different in all three environments you will define the variable three times and assign them their respective values for each environment and set the scope to each environment.

Comment: Scope is defined not for environment but two options: for entire release and for particular stage in release

Comment: Your stage = environment

Comment: viriables for diferent stages could not be same within same release, that is why stage!=environment

Comment: @SergSh - Are you saying that you have steps in a stage that have to use a different value for the same variable?  If yes, you have to create multiple variables.  For example, ServerName1, ServerName2 and Step1 uses ServerName1 & Step2 uses ServerName2 and the variables are still mapped to the Stage name of say Dev or QA.

Comment: I do not need such complexity. For instance I have auth server and have same steps to deploy it in different environments. All I want is only one variable AuthServerName but with different value for each environment,

Comment: Yes and you only have two choices to change the auth server in those steps.  Different environments = Stages in Release Pipelines.  You generally repeat the same steps in each stage but the variables have their values changed because of what was set for the stage is different for them in the Variables tab.  IF you don't use stages and choose to deploy to multiple auth servers in one stage, you have to use separate variables something like auth server 1, auth server 2.